# Elasticsearch: generating terms from array using script

Tags: elasticsearch

Would love an explanation of why this happens and how to correct it.

Here's a snippet of the source document:

```
{
   "created_time":1412988495000,
   "tags":{
      "items":[
         {
            "tag_type":"Placement",
            "tag_id":"id1"
         },
         {
            "tag_type":"Product",
            "tag_id":"id2"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The following terms aggregation:

```
  "aggs":{
       "tags":{
          "terms":{
             "script":"doc['tags'].value != null ? doc['tags.items.tag_type'].value + ':' + doc['tags.items.tag_id'].value : ''",
             "size":2000,
             "exclude":{
                "pattern":"null:null"
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

returns:

```
   "buckets":[
      {
         "key":"Placement:id1",
         "doc_count":1
      },
      {
         "key":"Placement:id2",
         "doc_count":1
      }
   ]
```

...when you would expect:

```
   "buckets":[
      {
         "key":"Placement:id1",
         "doc_count":1
      },
      {
         "key":"Product:id2",
         "doc_count":1
      }
   ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go with a [`nested type`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html). I don't know all the details of your setup, but here is a proof of concept, at least. I took out the `"items"` property because I didn't need that many layers, and just used `"tags"` as the `nested` type. It could be added back in if needed, I think.

So I set up an index with a `"nested"` property:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "created_time": {
               "type": "date"
            },
            "tags": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "tag_type": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "tag_id": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then added a couple of docs (notice that the structure differs slightly from yours):

```
PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
   "created_time": 1412988495000,
   "tags": [
      {
         "tag_type": "Placement",
         "tag_id": "id1"
      },
      {
         "tag_type": "Product",
         "tag_id": "id2"
      }
   ]
}

PUT /test_index/doc/2
{
   "created_time": 1412988475000,
   "tags": [
      {
         "tag_type": "Type3",
         "tag_id": "id3"
      },
      {
         "tag_type": "Type4",
         "tag_id": "id3"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now a [scripted `terms` aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) inside a [`nested aggregation`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) seems to do the trick:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "aggs": {
      "tags": {
         "nested": { "path": "tags" },
         "aggs":{
             "tag_vals": {
                 "terms": {
                     "script": "doc['tag_type'].value+':'+doc['tag_id'].value"
                 }
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "tags": {
         "doc_count": 4,
         "tag_vals": {
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "Placement:id1",
                  "doc_count": 1
               },
               {
                  "key": "Product:id2",
                  "doc_count": 1
               },
               {
                  "key": "Type3:id3",
                  "doc_count": 1
               },
               {
                  "key": "Type4:id3",
                  "doc_count": 1
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/4ceaf8693f85ff257c2fd0639ba62295f2e5e8c5

Comment: Thank you, found a similar case here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776428/elasticsearch-issue-with-sub-term-aggregation-with-array-fields